# How to output 0V for an input of <5V and 5V for an input of >6V

Tags: voltage

This question is in relation to an answer I made to my question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/490569/switch-between-2-voltage-dividers-depending-on-input-voltage?noredirect=1#). Wherein I need to enable the [TS12A12511](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts12a12511.pdf) depending on the input voltage. my input voltage can range from 3V to 9V.

The problem is that the TS12A12511 has different logic voltages for depending on VCC where in HIGH is 2.4V (when input V is 5V) and 5V (when input V is 12V). It does not say what is the voltage for input voltages that is in between. Since the input voltage is not fixed, to play it safe I must generate 0V and 5V to the IN pin of the IC.

[image]

How do I generate logic voltages (0V and 5V) for a set range of voltages. I would like for this magic circuit or IC to output 0V if the input voltage is less than 5V and to output 5V (or higher as long as it's less than the input voltage) if the input voltage is higher than 6V. Using minimal components and no components that need to be manipulated by the user.

I have tried to come up with some ideas to solve this but I have failed to come up with one that works, I have tried:

- Using a voltage divider configured in the image above, but the scaling is not linearly.
- Using a 5V regulator but it turns out voltage regulator starts producing voltages even if the input voltages does not reach 5V yet.
- Using a 5V regulator with Power/Good and Under voltage Lock out protection. Power good generates a signal way before 5V input.

Comment: If your 5V regulator generates a "power good" signal before the input reaches 5V, it's broken or has a very strange definition of "power good". Look for other regulators.

Comment: Generally, I think you're looking for Supply Supervisor ICs ([examples](http://www.ti.com/power-management/supervisor-reset-ic/overview.html)).

Comment: @MarcusMüller i could not find the exact one that i was reading the datasheet of. But i like the selections that you have linked. I found this [chip](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps3710.pdf) which i think i like. Post it as an answer good sir so i can accept it

Answer (score 1):

> *to play it safe I must generate 0v and 5v to the IN pin of the IC.*

No, because on a low supply you'll be likely destroying the device. The recommended operating conditions state that Vin should be between 0 volts and Vcc.

So, use a pull-up resistor (to Vcc whatever that is) and a MOSFET or BJT to drive the IN pin. There will be signal inversion so be aware of that. It's called an open collector or open drain circuit and the pull-up (1 kohm to 10 kohm) automatically fulfills the voltage level requirements set out in the data sheet: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, you are right i would over voltage the IC  during low power applications. But i think i have found the solution: use a Supply Supervisor IC. I think this chip [TPS3710](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps3710.pdf) should do the job

Comment: The simplicity of a transistor and resistor trumps the use of a chip IMHO.

Comment: Yes that is absolutely true, but i dont have confidence in myself yet well enough and might make a mistake on the circuit, as for the chip i for sure know it will work and even have access to the datasheet for a sample circuit.